# Are atoms and everything subatomic spherical?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics, atoms, subatomic

I was thinking about the structure of atoms and molecules. And i noticed everywhere we treat them spherical. Same thing about the subatomic particles.  How do we know  that these are spherical??

Comment: many nuclei have deformed ground states, as per here http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Shape_deformations_in_atomic_nuclei

Comment: Most molecules are definitely not spherical. A molecule of polyethylene may possibly be as long as your plastic bag. As we approach the subatomic level, classical concepts don't translate one to one to the quantum world. There you need to review what exactly you mean by "spherical", because the classical concept of "shape" has no meaning in the quantum world. You'd need to look from the perspective of the symmetry of interactions. Then you'll see things like spin and polarization. Are they the same as "non-spherical"? Depends on how you define "spherical" without defining "shape".

Answer (score 0):

Many molecules and some nuclei are not spherical. Some nuclei are known to have an oblate or prolate shape.  Particles like these are often treated initially as spherical since this helps sometimes in the description.